DAX problem when trying to sum quantity in different contexts
I am fairly new to DAX, and have had the (un)fortunate privilege of being responsible for a few measures that I cannot quite get right.
The first measure is called Store Weight and should sum QuantityKFP for all selected product categories (Product[Product Category]) for the selected customers, regardless of which product SKU is also selected (Product[SKU]) during the last 12 months, and looks as follows :
            SUM( Invoice[QuantityKFP] )
            , REMOVEFILTERS( Product[SKU] )
            , DATESBETWEEN( 'Time'[Day]
                , FIRSTDATE( DATESINPERIOD( 'Time'[Day], LASTDATE( 'Time'[Day] ), - 12, MONTH ) )
                , LASTDATE( 'Time'[Day] )
            )
        )

Say that the user chooses Customers A, B and C and Product Category 'Whiskey' and the SKU 'Johnny Walker'. Then the measure should sum the QuantityKFP for all the invoice rows for the selected Customers where products of the category 'Whisky' have been sold. This works in itself.
But then we have measure number 2, called 'Presence Store Weight'. This should do the same thing as 'Store Weight', except that if the selected SKU has no sales for a customer, ie it has QuantityKFP > 0 during the selected period, the sum for the Product Category should be treated as zero or ignored altogether for that customer. It looks as follows :
VAR _ProductPresence = FILTER( ALL(Customer[dmCustomerID]), [Quantity KFP] > 0 )

RETURN

    CALCULATE(
            SUM( Invoice[QuantityKFP] ) 
            , REMOVEFILTERS( Product[SKU] )
            , _ProductPresence
            ,DATESBETWEEN ( 'Time'[Day]
                        , FIRSTDATE( DATESINPERIOD('Time'[Day], LASTDATE('Time'[Day]), -12, MONTH) )
                        , LASTDATE('Time'[Day]) 
                    )
    )

For example; a user selects customers A, B and C. The user then selects 'Whiskey' as Product Category, and Johnny Walker as Product SKU, and time period as 202401. Customers A and B have sales of Johnny Walker during 202401, but customer C has not. The measure should then sum QuantityKFP for the Product Category 'Whisky' for the last 12 months ONLY for customers A and B.
I am sure this could be written better, but it seems to work, UNLESS the SKU that is being chosen does not belong to any of the chosen product categories. Then I get only a blank row. This would be for example if the product category chosen is 'Whiskey', but the sku is 'Coca Cola'. I am not sure how to get this to work, so I am grateful for any help.
/David
